# Multiple parameter input in sql excel query

Tags: sql, excel, parameters, where-in

I am trying to have multiple inputs into a excel/sql query.

basis of what I need is this: 
where ProductID IN (?)

I have the parameter working when I enter a single ProductID, but I want to add multiple, ideally via a list in cells A1:A20, but the list may only be 1 or 2 long, or anywhere up to 20 values (could need to be longer, but can live with max length).

I have tried ="'"&A1&"','"&A2&"',"etc and pointed the parameter to that cell.

(Using Excel 2010, connecting to a SQL 2008R2)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your application structure? Where do you run the query from? Is the Excel linked or do you open it with VBA?

Comment: SQL Query is run from External Data Properties in excel, connecting to MS SQL database.  Not using VBA as have very little knowledge of VBA.